# Разделить слова до минимума

Tags: теги, php

Всем привет, в php не особо силен - поэтому не знаю как правильно описать задачу.
Поэтому сразу к примеру:

```
search.php?q=free-online-film-view
```

Нужно чтобы **free-online-film-view**, превратился так

```
search.php?q=free-online-film

search.php?q=free-online

search.php?q=free
```

То есть чтобы слово разделилось до минимума
и чтобы вид был такой

```
<ul>
<li><a href="search.php?q=free-online-film">free online film</a></li>
<li><a href="search.php?q=free-online">free online</a></li>
<li><a href="search.php?q=free">free</a></li>
</ul>
```

Спасибо

Comment: @jikol, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить [такой вариант](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/f13-5vw):

```
$str = 'search.php?q=free-online-film-view';
$main_parts = explode('=',$str);
$vals = explode('-',$main_parts[1]);
for($i = 0; $i <= count($vals); $i++){
    array_pop($vals);
    echo $main_parts[0].'='.implode('-',$vals).'<br>';
}
```

Еще можно восспользоваться вариантом, с использованием [strrpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strrpos.php), находя последнее вхождение символа "-" в строке и срезая строку до него. Но на мой взгляд - это более геморройный способ.

Comment: Скрипт работает, я его немного подправил под себя.Вот
    echo '<li><a href="'.$main_parts[0].'='.implode('-',$vals).'">'.''.implode(' ',$vals).''.'</a></li>';

Но есть косяк, который не знаю как решить

Если у нас $str = 'search.php?q=free';
то выходит вот какая штука 
<a href="search.php?q="></a>
Как решить, чтобы не выводило так, если слова не делятся

Comment: Проверку можно делать:

if(count($vals) > 1) {
 for($i = 0; $i <= count($vals); $i++){
  echo $main_parts[0].'='.implode('-',$vals).'<br>';
  array_pop($vals);
  
 }
} else {
 // вывод исходной строки
}

Comment: Сработало, но при запросе
search.php?q=free-online
выдает так:
<li><a href="search.php?q=free-online">free online</a></li>
<li><a href="search.php?q="></a></li>

Comment: Ну, дык почему сразу не указать в вопросе, что кол-во таких параметров, может варьироваться от 1 до N? Или есть еще какие-то нюансы? [Смотрите по ссылке][1].

   [1]:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xbi-qr3

Comment: Спасибо, я как-то не подумал об этом.
Прости, если что-то ни так.
Все работает превосходно!
Огромное спасибо за терпение и помощь в выполнение поставленной задачи...

Comment: Или даже [таким способом][1] можно:

   [1]:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7gm-wu3

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить немного другой вариант:

```
$str = "free-online-film-view";
$tags = explode("-", $str);
$i=count($tags);
foreach($tags as $tag){
    echo "li - ". implode('-', array_slice($tags,0, $i--))."\n";
}
```

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/vRZkpE)